# Xcode Model I/O - importing custom shader from Marmoset

Tags: xcode8, scenekit, swift4, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

Accordion to Apple Model I/o documentation:

> Block quote

You can use this framework to import and export assets from and to a variety of industry standard file formats supported by popular authoring tools and game engines.

> Block quote

And

> Block quote

Describing realistic rendering parameters. TheMDLPhysicallyPlausibleScatteringFunction class—one of many ways to describe the surface appearance for a MDLMaterial object associated with a mesh—defines the intended rendering of a surface using the same physically based shading systems seen in popular feature films and high-end game engines. The MDLPhotometricLight and MDLPhysicallyPlausibleLight classes describe realistic lighting properties for use in rendering, and the MDLCamera class also supports physically based rendering parameters.

> Block quote

So,it it possible to import a custom PBR shader created in Marmoset?

If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation (of MDLAsset) also includes:

“The set of supported formats includes Alembic (.abc), Wavefront Object (.obj), Polygon (.ply), and Standard Tessellation Language (.stl). Additional formats may be supported as well.”

From marmoset.co:
“Marmoset Toolbag uses a somewhat customized shader language, which is a kind of union of HLSL and GLSL syntax conventions”

Metal uses it’s own [shading language](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) and is not even supported by the file formats it can import and export. So in short, no, you can’t import those shaders.